# Node js Serial port stops receiving data after a while

Tags: node.js, arduino, serial-port

I am fetching the sensor data from 'Arduino nano' using the byte length parser. The frames are accurate, however, I stop receiving the frames after a few minutes. I have the same piece of code in Matlab and it works perfectly fine, meaning that there is no problem at the device end. Something's wrong at Nodejs side. I want my node server to continuously receive the data

```
Code to Reproduce the Issue
var portName = "/dev/ttyACM1";
const myPort = new Serialport(portName, {
baudRate: 115200,
xon: true,
xoff: true
});

const Delimiter = require("@serialport/parser-delimiter");
const parser1 = myPort.pipe(new Delimiter({ delimiter: "\n" }));

parser1.on("data", data => {
}
```

// parser.on works for few minutes and then stops receiving data

Comment: I see you have also filed an issue at https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/issues/2113

Comment: Thanks for replying, yes you are correct. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Comment: Well, the only thing I could think of initially is node.js generally has a socket and they can timeout, but the default is for a socket not to time out.

Comment: So, the question is, have you tried the `stream` version of the serial port api? The one you're using might have a default timeout that isn't adjustable. It may be a "wait for data and read" and then close whereas the streaming might be "open forever"

Comment: The final thing I can think of is that node/arduino disconnects and there is no retry to connect logic. --- sorry I don't know anything about the serial port api so I can't be of more help